# Android actionbar background around title

Tags: android, xml, background, android-actionbar

Android Studio 1.1.0. SDK 22 Installed&Compiled, SDK 17 Target (I suppose it's not relevant, because issue occurs also on preview in IDE).

I started playing with Holo theme action bar styling and ran into an issue, involving background color. This is my styles.xml:

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">#ff0d3200</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/BarTheme</item>
    </style>

    <style name="BarTheme" parent="android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">#443322</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

And this is output. I want app title's background color to be the same as action bar's. As I've said, it's the same on the preview, so I don't think it's because my phone(SDK17) or emulator. Overflow button behaves the same way, there just isn't any in this case.

[image]

I tried setting android:titleTextStyle in BarTheme to this style:

```
<style name="TitleTheme" parent="android:TextAppearance.Holo">
    <item name="android:background">#443322</item>
</style>
```

But it didn't change a thing. What do I do to overcome this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to David's input I solved my problem myself. I had to set `windowBackground`, instead of `background` in AppTheme. I'm not sure what is the exact difference, but it works properly. Remember not to change attribute in your BarTheme, because it won't work with `windowBackground`. Therefore correct `styles.xml` file is:

```
<resources>

    <color name="bcColor">#ff0d3200</color>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/bcColor</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/BarTheme</item>
    </style>

    <style name="BarTheme" parent="android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">#443322</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Note that color has to be defined as resource in this case and cannot be hardcoded. The clean way to do this is create colors.xml in values folder and define all colors there.

Answer (score 1):

try ,

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>




<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">value</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/TitleColor</item>
</style>



<style name="TitleColor" parent="android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">value</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Well, that didn't change anything. I also tried using `@android:/style` instead of  `android:` in other styles, but also nothing. By the way, what's the difference? Is on of them deprecated or something?

Comment: i have edit the answer and this is working , try that

Comment: Actually, you just deleted main background, so it doesn't interfere with action bar, but I want to be able to manipulate this too.

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but solution was to use windowBackground instead of background in AppTheme style.

Comment: were you able to change the textcolor using windowbackground ? if so, can you post the anwser plz ?

Comment: Yes, i copy-pasted your code, changed attribute to windowBackground, typed in some random values and everything, including text color works like a charm. I added code to the end of my question (without textColor, because it wasn't the topic).